# What is latest UX for this simple design?

Tags: ux-field

In this image,we have assessment management screen.In this screen we have organizational assessment which contain number of assessments.These assessment have 2 stage i.e. published and in-progress.we have one more button on top which can use to add assessment.This screen seems really simple so i need some better UX for this screen.

[image]

Comment: You're asking for a lot of work here: "I need some better UX" sounds a lot like "can someone do some free UX work for me". Is there a specific problem you're experiencing with this screen? What have you already tried and discounted? What is the context of the screen? Where does this screen come in your user journey?... there are many more questions we would ask about this. This is not a board for soliciting work but for solving UX problems.

Comment: Like Andrew said, you cannot just say here is my simple design pls insert ux. If you want inspiration or to follow latest UI trends try www.uplabs.com  or www.behance.net